# C++ Storing different range operations in the same variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I'm implementing a custom iterator that is parametrized with range types:

```
template <std::ranges::range Container> class CustomIterator{}
```

The iterator is then used like this: `auto t = CustomIterator<decltype(result)>(result);`
result being of type `std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>`.

The problem is when I want to replace the custom iterator with another one that is parametrized with a type that is the result of another ranges operation.

Is there a base class for `std::ranges::filter_view` or is there any other way to store a `CustomIterator` of `std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>`, `std::ranges::reverse_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>` etc. in the same variable?

```
CustomIterator<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>>
CustomIterator<std::ranges::reverse_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>>
```

Is there a way to store the above two in the same variable in a flexible way(not using std::variant for a specific case).

Comment: What's the point of doing this? What do you want `CustomIterator` to do? It seems like you want a type-erased iterator type, which is probably extremely inefficient.

Comment: The iterator would do circular iteration. Is there a reason why holding a range as a class member would be a bad idea? What would be an alternative to implementing such an iterator?

Comment: Look at `std::make_pair()` function. It gives an example of using a function to create an object without having to manually specify the type (As the compiler can do type deduction on function parameters that can then be used to create the correct object type).

Comment: `auto t = make_CustomIterator(result);`